# qpid AMQConnection.createSession() producing duplicate Session objects?

Tags: session, jms, hashcode, qpid

I have a bunch of threads, each creating an `org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnection` and then a session.

```
public void run() {
    Connection connection = new AMQConnection("amqp://*******:*****@clientid/test?brokerlist='tcp://********:****?sasl_mechs='ANONYMOUS''");
    connection.start();

    Session ssn = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);    
    System.out.println(ssn.toString());

    ssn.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

On some runs, I get the same Session.hashCode() in two different threads like so:

```
org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession_0_10@420e44
org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession_0_10@d76237
org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession_0_10@d76237
org.apache.qpid.client.AMQSession_0_10@7148e9
```

Now I understand `hashcode()` is not guaranteed to be unique, how can I prove or disprove that `createSession()` returns the same session object on two separate threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be more of a Java object equivalency question rather than anything to do with qpid or messaging.

Instead of printing hashcodes, I inserted the `Session` objects themselves into a `Vector<Session>` and compared them (`==`). Turns out they were all unique across all threads.